# Maven Spring boot dependency vs Maven Spring dependency

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies

What is the difference between the way I declare the two dependency?
My project is a spring boot project...
This one I downloaded from Spring Initializer:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This one is from mvnrepository.com:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**Update**, this [article](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/) shows a third way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a Spring Boot starter. According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter):

> Starters are a set of convenient dependency descriptors that you can include in your application. You get a one-stop shop for all the Spring and related technologies that you need without having to hunt through sample code and copy-paste loads of dependency descriptors.

The [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-data-ldap/pom.xml) of [`spring-boot-starter-data-ldap`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-data-ldap) contains the following dependency definitions:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-ldap</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The second one: [`spring-security-ldap`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/ldap) is the artifact present in maven central, corresponding to the [Spring LDAP project](https://spring.io/projects/spring-ldap).